# Is it possible to manipulate the audio from a WebRTC peer connection mediastream with Web Audio API?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, webrtc, web-audio-api

Our app currently streams audio and video from other peers using WebRTC. We want to add effects to the audio with web audio API. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, how? Thanks!

(examples would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: I am using the simpleWebRTC library

Comment: You might be able to do this using  context.createMediaElementSource()

Comment: here is a Web Audio hack article   http://noisehack.com/custom-audio-effects-javascript-web-audio-api/